# Angular navigate to route with multiple params

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to navigate from one page to another, but by keeping previous params in the URL.

Example

```
currentRoute = '/b/users/edit;id=5cf691d8d2bbcf881ad4c792/village/store/edit;name=GameStore'
```

I want to be able to navigate to the following page

```
/b/users/edit;id=5cf691d8d2bbcf881ad4c792/path/new;r=GameStore
```

I am not sure how to pass multiple params but in different locations in the URL.
Essentially what I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
this.router.navigate([`/b/user/edit`, {id: this.userid}, `/path/new`, { r: this.router.url }])
```

EDIT

So this is my routing structure:

```
{
    path: 'b',
    children: [{
        path: 'users',
        children: [{
            path: 'edit',
            children: [{
                path: 'village',
                children: [{
                    path: 'store,
                    children: [{
                        path: 'edit',
                        component : editBVillageStoreComponent
                    }],
                    path: 'path',
                    children: [{
                        path: 'new',
                        component: 'newBVillagePathComponent'
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
]}
```

So basically I want to jump from one component to another, but keeping the parent params.

I tried using `{relativeTo: true}` with no luck.  I might have just been using it wrong though.

Comment: What is the current route without params? And the one which you want to go to?

Comment: @Arcteezy I updated my answer with a routing structure

Comment: You should use `queryParams` for such complex routing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to route to the path: 'path' which is a child of 'village'. Technically, the child component should follow the parent.

As per Angular documentation, child routes extend the path of the parent route. So either your routing configuration is wrong or the way you are trying to achieve navigation to the child path 'path'.

So, maybe this is something you want to do:
`` this.router.navigate([`/b/user/edit`, {id: this.userid}, `/village/path/new`, { r: this.router.url }]) ``

Answer (score 0):

You could set up your route like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "b",
    children: [
      {
        path: "users/:id",
        children: [
          {
            path: "edit",
            children: [
              {
                path: "village",
                children: [
                  {
                    path: "store",
                    children: [
                      {
                        path: "edit/:id",
                        component: HelloComponent
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    path: "path",
                    children: [
                      {
                        path: "new",
                        component: HelloComponent
                      }]}]}]}]}]}
];
```

and then navigate:

```
this.router.navigate([`/b/users/${this.userId}/edit/village/store/edit/${this.storeId}`]);
```

Check this Stackblitz example I made based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvbkej

Click the button to navigate. Check the generated URL.